# An error occurred while connecting to camera in android

Tags: android-camera, zxing

During integration of zxing library in android app every thing works fine but when i try to call camera repeatedly facing this problem with camera
here is my logcat

```
    02-24 20:49:34.775: W/CameraBase(15622): An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622): Unexpected error initializing camera
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:545)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:385)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.OpenCameraInterface.open(OpenCameraInterface.java:53)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.CameraManager.openDriver(CameraManager.java:80)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.initCamera(CaptureActivity.java:652)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.surfaceCreated(CaptureActivity.java:370)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:607)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:184)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:921)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2169)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1196)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6675)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
02-24 20:49:34.785: W/CaptureActivity(15622):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

Here is code for integrating zxing library please check it

```
    @Override
    public void onScanClicked(int position) {
        barCodePosition = position;
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "SCAN_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 123);
    }
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // We came from the scanning activity; the return intent contains a
        // RESULT_EXTRA key
        // whose value is an ArrayList of BarcodeResult objects that we found
        // while scanning.
        // Get the list of objects and add them to our list view.
        System.out
                .println(requestCode + "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD" + resultCode);
        switch (requestCode) {

        case SCAN_CODE:

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                ArrayList<BarcodeResult> barcodes = data
                        .getParcelableArrayListExtra(BarcodeScanActivity.RESULT_EXTRA);
                if (barcodes != null && barcodes.size() > 0) {
                    BarcodeResult barCodeResult = barcodes.get(0);
                    String barCodeNumber = barCodeResult.barcodeString;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), barCodeNumber,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    scanAdapter.addBarcodes(barCodeNumber, barCodePosition);

                }
            }

            break;

        case SCANNER_REQ_CODE:

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                System.out.println(contents
                        + "TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT");
                scanAdapter.addBarcodes(contents, barCodePosition);

            }

            break;

        case gps_code:
            switch (resultCode) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Bundle bund = data.getExtras();
                outletLatitude = bund.getString("LATITUDE");
                outletLongitude = bund.getString("LONGITUDE");
                diag = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait",
                        "saving data...");
                thd = new Thread(StockCountActivity.this);
                thd.start();
                break;

            default:
            }
        case product_code:
            switch (resultCode) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Bundle bund = data.getExtras();
                // purchaseVolume.setText(bund.getString("SALES_VOLUME"));
                // purchaseValue.setText(bund.getString("SALES_VALUE"));
                // salesDetails = bund.getString("SALES_DETAILS");
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                break;
            default:
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Has you problem solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Comment: Hi, when answering questions on SO please add further information on how the user might be able to complete your instructions. Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: [W/CameraBase﹕ An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996819/w-camerabase-an-error-occurred-while-connecting-to-camera-0/33244795#33244795)

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example, a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen. http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html