# Android Studio - (zxing) W/CameraBase﹕ An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0

Tags: android, camera, zxing

There was a similar question but I have not found the solution. I am using Android Studio and this error occured all phones.

I have an app which is using the camera for the scan qrcode.
The app work like this, firstly when I open application camera is work smoothly and it is scan qrcode when it's scan qrcode I see the result another activity after this point there is a button for the scan another qrcode this button goes to preview activity in this point the camera is seem black.

The full log out is;

```
02-12 11:23:11.387 25722-25722/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
02-12 11:23:11.387 25722-25722/? E/Zygote: v2
02-12 11:23:11.387 25722-25722/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10459
02-12 11:23:11.387 25722-25722/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
02-12 11:23:11.412 25722-25722/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-N9000Q_5.0 ver=27
02-12 11:23:11.412 25722-25722/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [1] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-N9000Q_5.0_0027
02-12 11:23:11.417 25722-25722/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
02-12 11:23:11.417 25722-25722/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-12 11:23:11.452 25722-25722/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
02-12 11:23:11.452 25722-25722/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
02-12 11:23:11.497 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler D/ResourcesManager: creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.molekul.cografiisaretler-1/base.apk
02-12 11:23:11.697 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png
02-12 11:23:11.717 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler E/onCreate: onCreate
02-12 11:23:11.732 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler D/Activity: performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
02-12 11:23:11.732 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler D/Activity: performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
02-12 11:23:11.787 25722-25798/com.molekul.cografiisaretler D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
02-12 11:23:11.792 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler D/Atlas: Validating map...
02-12 11:23:11.827 25722-25798/com.molekul.cografiisaretler I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-12 11:23:11.837 25722-25798/com.molekul.cografiisaretler I/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0xaeb22088 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = -1363909708 
02-12 11:23:11.857 25722-25798/com.molekul.cografiisaretler D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-12 11:23:12.572 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler I/Choreographer: Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-12 11:23:13.137 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1b9b925c time:14318576
02-12 11:23:16.747 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
02-12 11:23:16.897 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1b9b925c time:14322338
02-12 11:23:25.507 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler E/SONUC: 18838813
02-12 11:23:25.507 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler E/SONUC: UPC_E
02-12 11:23:25.507 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.molekul.cografiisaretler time:14330949
02-12 11:23:25.547 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png
02-12 11:23:25.552 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler E/onCreate: onCreate
02-12 11:23:25.577 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable/cross64.png
02-12 11:23:25.582 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler D/Activity: performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
02-12 11:23:25.582 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler D/Activity: performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
02-12 11:23:25.592 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
02-12 11:23:26.077 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@342580a7 time:14331515
02-12 11:23:26.087 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{2d9f8043 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1b9b925c {com.molekul.cografiisaretler/com.molekul.cografiisaretler.MainActivity}} show : false
02-12 11:23:26.632 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
02-12 11:23:26.797 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.molekul.cografiisaretler time:14332236
02-12 11:23:26.827 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler E/onCreate: onCreate
02-12 11:23:26.827 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler D/Activity: performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
02-12 11:23:26.827 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler D/Activity: performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
02-12 11:23:26.832 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
02-12 11:23:26.962 25722-25798/com.molekul.cografiisaretler D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x9c50ce00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xaeb17430
02-12 11:23:27.002 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@b3f84 time:14332441
02-12 11:23:27.387 25722-25722/com.molekul.cografiisaretler V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{163c736d token=android.os.BinderProxy@342580a7 {com.molekul.cografiisaretler/com.molekul.cografiisaretler.informationActivity}} show : false
```

Main Activity;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{


    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.e("onCreate", "onCreate");
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(mScannerView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

            mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
            mScannerView.startCamera();

    }


    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {

        Log.e("SONUC", rawResult.getText());
        Log.e("SONUC", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());


        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, informationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

information Activity;

```
public class informationActivity extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_information);


    }
    public void yenidenTara(View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(informationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

Comment: where's the code that opens/closes the `Camera`?

Comment: can you please share Manifest file

Comment: I shared Manifest file  @Ajinkya

Comment: I fixex MainActivity @Shark

Answer (score 1):

Sorry! My Fault  this is the MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{

        Integer response = 0 ;

        private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Log.e("onCreate", "onCreate");
            mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
            setContentView(mScannerView);

        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            if(response == 1) {
                mScannerView = null;
                mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
                setContentView(mScannerView);
                response = 0;

            }

                mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
                mScannerView.startCamera();

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

            mScannerView = null;
            mScannerView.stopCamera();

        }


        @Override
        public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {

            Log.e("SONUC", rawResult.getText());
            Log.e("SONUC", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, informationActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.molekul.xx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.molekul.xx.informationActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure your app request/has enabled the proper permission as mentioned here [W/CameraBase﹕ An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996819/w-camerabase-an-error-occurred-while-connecting-to-camera-0/33244795#33244795)

I was facing the same problem until I enable the permission in Settings>Apps>YourApp>Permissions

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mScannerView = null;
        mScannerView.stopCamera();

    }
```

first you make variable null, then try to call method on it. It might cause NullPointerException, and also there's no guarantee that stopCamera() is ever called. So the next request to camera hardware might stuck cause previous client haven't released the camera yet. try first to switch calles in places

Comment: so what do you mean exactly. I didnt understand

Comment: `CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0` usually means that another process took hold on camera hardware. In your case, probably after first use of camera you didn't call `stopCamera()`, because you made your `mScannerView` null before calling stop().

Comment: You should put mScannerView = null after stopping de camera otherwise it is going to crash.