# Crash when accessing camera?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a simple flashlight app and when I test, the app crashes. I think that there's something wrong when trying to access camera. Any suggestions?

```
W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
I/Camera2Mode: fail
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:479)
at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:547)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226)
at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:122)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95       
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)


at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)

D/Process: killProcess, pid=23317
D/Process: com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:113 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690 
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8603', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: post your manifest code please. which permissions you give there?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/23904459/android-java-lang-runtimeexception-fail-to-connect-to-camera-service

Comment: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> try using this two line in manifest

Comment: Yes I added the permissions already    

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put camera permission in manifest file like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Other thing that can link to this problem refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996819/w-camerabase-an-error-occurred-while-connecting-to-camera-0) link

Answer (score 1):

There can be two issues. One is permission which is easy to handle.Also be careful while permission handling in case you are developing apps for Android 6.0 Just add this in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
```

Another is while you are trying to open your camera may be there is another application which is using camera that time. 
So for avoiding exception you need to wrap up opening camera in a try-catch block. 
like this:

```
    static Camera camera = null;
    try{ 
       camera = Camera.open();
      } catch(Exception e) {
       Log.e("Error", ""+e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

and for SDK 23 and above

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your test mobile is 6.0+,you should use your code request permission,or else you can reduce the version of build